# Not-significant F but a significant coefficient in multiple linear regression

Tags: multiple-regression, f-test

I have  a regression with two continuous predictors and one dichotomous predictor in Model 1 and two interactions of each of the continuous predictors with the dichotomous predictor in Model 2. The coefficient for one of the interaction terms is significant. However, the F test is not significant (neither for Model 1 nor for Model 2). Should I still interpret that significant interaction or should I just assume that neither the predictors, nor the interaction terms are useful in predicting the outcome variable?

Comment: Does model 2 also have the main effects from model 1 in it?

Comment: Yes, it has the two main effects + the two interactions.

Comment: Also of interest: [Significance-of-coefficients-in-linear-regression:-significant-t-test-vs-non-sigificant-F-statistic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24720/).

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like your F-tests are not the ones you want, the default F-tests returned by most software compare the fitted model to a null (intercept-only) model.  It sounds like you want to do an F-test comparing Model 2 to Model 1.

If you do this, you could still find that the F-test comparing these two models is insignificant, while the t-test on one of the interactions is significant.  It is important to keep in mind that these are different tests, answering slightly different questions.  The t-test on the interaction term is a test of how strongly the data reject the hypothesis that the interaction term is zero, *holding fixed all the other coefficients in the extended model, including the other added interaction term*.  The F-test is a test of how strongly the data reject the hypothesis that all the added terms are zero.

If the two terms you added in the extended model have one t-stat that is narrowly significant and another that is insignificant, the F-test can be insignificant.  One way to think about why this can happen is that adding multiple terms to a model creates a multiple testing problem. The chances of spuriously finding a large coefficient on one of the interaction terms increases as you add more terms.  The F-test takes this into account, while the individual t-tests for each term do not.