# Non-significant group effect, but LSD post hoc is significant. Why?

Tags: anova, post-hoc

I am performing repeated ANOVAs in SPSS and came across something I don't understand.

Basically, the main effect of group (I have three groups) is not significant (p = .062), but the LSD *post hoc* test indicates that one of the pair-wise comparisons is significant (p = .032).

How is that possible?

Comment: This is essentially the same issue as here: [significance-of-coefficients-in-linear-regression-significant-t-test-vs-non-significant-F-statistic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24720/). You should read that & see if you have any lingering questions left over. If so, edit this Q to specify clearly what you still need to know; if not, this Q should be closed. You could flag a moderator for attention to help w/ that.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. HERE (http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2lx6o95&s=6) I have put a schematic of the two groups that I have. Almost all the data points in two groups are significantly different according to Tukey (I'm using Sigmaplot, Two way repeated measures ANOVA), but there is no significant effect of group. There is significant effect of time and "time X Group". I'm wondering how should I interpret the data. Group 1 and 2 in the link below signifies two various treatment options.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this was abandoned by the OP without clarification.