# SPSS Output - My Omnibus Test is insignificant, but I have significant predictors

Tags: regression, spss

I ran a binary-logistic regression in SPSS. Block 1 shows that the Omnibus Tests of Model Coefficients is insignificant for step, block and model, p =1.06. However, I have two significant predictors in the Variables in the Equation Table. Because the Omnibus test is insignificant, are my two predictors also insignificant? I am not sure how to report the results.

Thank you for any help! This is part of my dissertation research.

Comment: The whole point to the omnibus test is to prevent you from looking at such individual predictors until the omnibus test says that would be worthwhile doing.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24720 for further discussion of this situation.

Comment: p=1.06? Is this the kind of p-value that SPSS reports?

Comment: I reported the p wrong, SPSS showed p=.106

Comment: Can I share my SPSS output - with a Google Link? I think it would make more sense to look at it.

Comment: Sure, if you have reason to believe the duplicate doesn't address the question you have.