# Non-significant MANOVA with significant planned contrasts

Tags: manova, contrasts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Not-significant F but a significant coefficient in multiple linear regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13850/not-significant-f-but-a-significant-coefficient-in-multiple-linear-regression)
>   [How can you have a non-significant multiple regression model w/ significant predictors?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34797/how-can-you-have-a-non-significant-multiple-regression-model-w-significant-pred)

My hypothesis was that social engagement would be associated with cognition. I set up a one-way MANOVA in SPSS to look at the association between social engagement (IV, 9 levels) and performance on 6 different cognitive tests. Because the IV had so many levels, I also set up a series of planned contrasts (equivalent to Helmert contrasts) so that I could see where the real difference lay. The overall ANOVAs came back as non-significant for all DVs bar one. However, for 3 of the tests, the same planned contrast came up as significant (p<0.01).

How could the planned contrasts come up as significant if the overall ANOVA was not? And how do I report this? Please help!

Answer (score 2):

Planned comparisons are usually powerful but you´ll need to check if Helmert contrast are a type of ORTHOGONAL contrast (independent). If Helmert contrast is in fact a non-orthogonal contrast then you have to adjust the alpha level using Bonferroni, or other procedures, since you are inflating type I error in the comparisons.